# Cannot Upload to Google Drive

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a JSON file to the root folder in whoever's GDrive. I've search all through Google for an answer while trying to fix it myself. No matter what I've done request.Responsebody always returns null. Here I tried to do a blank .txt file (which still doesn't work).

This is the code to get the credentials and then it sets the resulting DeviceService to variable.

```
//GDrive Cred
public static void GetCred()
{
    //Get Credential
    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream =
        new FileStream(Path + "\\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart");

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }

    // Create Drive API service.
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });

    mService = service;
}
```

and this is the code to upload the file.

```
//Save JSON to GDrive
public static void SaveJSONtoDrive()
{

    GetCred();
    // File's metadata.
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
    body.Title = "ATGEntries.txt";
    body.Description = "Database JSON for Adventurer's Tour Guide";
    //body.MimeType = "application/json";
    body.MimeType = "text/plain";
    body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = "root" } };

    // File's content.
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path + "\\ATGEntries.txt");
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    try
    {
        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = mService.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.UploadAsync();

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;

        // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
        Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);

    }
}
```

Can someone please attempt to help me fix this strange error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot believe this isn't anywhere so I will answer my own question in the hopes that it will help someone else along the way.

Pay attention to the line where you set the 'credPath' variable

```
credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart");
```

make sure the part after  ".credentials/" needs to be the same name as whatever you named your OAuth 2.0 client ID in the Google Developers Console. This should fix the problem.